# Sort Currency Data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet where i have a Column with Format "Currency". When i sort on this column it is not sorting properly seems like taking data as "String".

Here is an  example

```
Potential Amount
$9,421
$86,533
$12,727
$77,720
```

should be sort to following

```
Potential Amount
$9,421
$12,727
$77,720
$86,533
```

Is there any way to keep data format "Currency" like $8,99,4 and make sorting work as well.

Please advise.

Comment: Is 'example' the current sort result gives?

Comment: No, current sort gives this $9,421 $77,720 $12,727 $86,533

Comment: I just tried copying the data into excel right clicked column said format, currency.  Then went to data and clicked sort with headers and I encountered your desired results.  Try copying the data to a different sheet/workbook and try again.

Comment: I think that some of your currency amounts are stored as text. Try running a Find/Replace to remove all the `$`, and reformat the column as currency.

Comment: Please try this data  $1,694
$1,974
$10,202
$103,125
$106,694
$119,004
$12,363
$12,392
$12,727
$128,614
$13,182
$14,014

Comment: When you select all the currency columns in excel and right-Click and select Sort...Are you Getting the option "Sort Smallest to Largest"...If yes then the column is of Type currency. Then sort shuld work properly

Comment: i m getting A to Z and Z to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to replicate your problem by formatting some of the data as text and some as currency.

As I don't have enough points to comment(at this point), I'll leave an answer instead. The comment left by Jerry under your original question should fix your problem.

It looks like some of your data has a different format. Please select **ALL** of your data and reformat it as currency.

Then re-sort the data.

Comment: yes some data has Text format, i select ALL reformat it as currency. And it works, thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

Seems all values are string. Covert it to values like

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)))
```

Then format-cell apply currency with $ symbol. Now you can apply sorting.